# Are there data grid components in JSF/PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need an iterating component like a `<h:datatable>` which generates `<div>` elements on every iteration and adds pagination. Something like an `<ui:repeat>` with pagination.

Does it exist in PrimeFaces or any other library?

Answer (score 2):

I think the **p:dataTable** element in PrimeFaces does what you want.  It draws a pagination panel with first/prior/next/last control semantics.  Here is the [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatablePagination.jsf) for pagination.

What I recommend most is their "lazy data table loading" mode where you do not transfer any data from the server to the client that is not actually going to be displayed.  In this way you can handle a data source with millions of records.  Here is the [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) for lazy data loading.

If you want a grid and not a table, I think the PrimeFaces **p:dataGrid** implementation is the best in the business.  Unfortunately my own application doesn't use it, but the example is [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datagrid.jsf).